# Node.js database access does it block main thread?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading

I've read up a good bit on node.js and I'm  a little confused as what constitutes thread blocking in a node.js server, in this case connecting to a db (heroku postgres)

Take for example:

```
app.get('/search', function(req, res){
    var id = req.query.q;
    **connect to db find items**
         callback ------> **another db transaction**
                    callback ------> res.json({some:data});

});
```

My question is if this would block the main thread? Does everything that interacts with an npm module get thrown through the event loop, therefore non blocking? Is there a general rule or set of guidelines that defines what is and what isn't thread blocking?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, most functions whose names that don't end in `Sync` and take in a callback, return an `EventEmitter`, return a `Promise`, etc., are async. That's about as close to a "general rule" as it gets these days. To be absolutely sure however, you should consult the module's documentation.

For Postgres specifically (`pg` module), connecting, querying, etc. are all done asynchronously and would not block the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Further to mscdex's answer, any function that returns the value you want directly (not via callback/promise/etc) definitely does block the thread.